# How to install OpenCV on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, opencv, windows-7, eclipse-plugin

I've downloaded `OpenCV`, and I have tried to "connect it with Eclipse" without success, if anyone knows how it works please help me.

Comment: Can you already use it from command line?

Comment: Hi there, what's the os you use and what openCV release do you try, anyway maybe some videos might help http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=opencv+eclipse&oq=opencv+eclipse&gs_l=youtube-reduced.12...0.0.0.9067.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.

Comment: @phimuemue , I 'm using windows7, @ theNewone I already watched that and it didn't help :(

Comment: There is an eclipse plugin... check on https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+plugin+eclipse

Comment: @anishsane  it helps a lot :(

Answer (score 0):

Install the CDT C++ plugin in Eclipse. Or else download the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.
Then go to Eclipse. File -> New -> C/C++ Project.
Create a project as per your need.
From here its not that difficult.
Once the project is created you can adjust other settings from project properties. YOu will also find the OpenCV settings here.

Comment: I already did that it doesn't work, the problem is linking eclipse with the lib of OpenCV2.4.2

Comment: are you using a windows system or linux?

Comment: http://carrierfrequency.blogspot.in/2011/05/opencv-22-in-windows-using-eclipse-ide.html           try this link it helps a lot for setting up on windows system. I tried using it and mine worked properly.

Comment: Also remember not to install OpenCv in the Program Files folder. It gives issues a lot of times.

Comment: Also you might have to change the library path in eclipse as shown on the above link. Under OpenCV2.4.2 you will have it under OpenCV/build/x64(x86 for 32 bit)/mingw/lib/

Comment: Plus the libraries that you have to select would be more as the list below:opencv_calib3d242

opencv_contrib242

opencv_core242

opencv_features2d242

libopencv_flann242

libopencv_gpu242

libopencv_highgui242

libopencv_imgproc242

libopencv_legacy242

libopencv_ml242

libopencv_nonfree242 
libopencv_objdetect242
libopencv_photo242
libopencv_stitching242
libopencv_ts242
libopencv_video242
libopencv_videostab242